# php code, better way of grabbing sql data

Tags: php, sql, join

I need to grab data from two tables, but I know theres a better, more tidier way to do this. Is it some kind of JOIN i need?

I'll show you my code and you'll see what I mean:

```
if ($rs[firearm] != "") {
   $sql_result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db_firearms WHERE name='$rs[firearm]'", $db);
   $rs2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result2);
   $sql_result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items_firearms WHERE player='$id'", $db);
   $rs3 = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result3);

    if ($rs3[$rs2[shortname]] < 1) {
       mysql_query("UPDATE mobsters SET firearm = '' WHERE id ='$id'");
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the first query, please.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do, because you haven't commented your code, nor have you given us an idea of your table layout.  But it looks likes you're trying to choose a particular database column based on the value of another query result, which sounds like a pretty bad idea.

Comment: why is it a bad idea? is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This question is clear, but your code example has alot of formatting issues and I cannot give you direct answer, based on your example code.

The reason, why your example is unclear, is because.. with what are you going to join the tables? From one table you are selecting by `name='$rs[firearm]'` and from another by `player='$id'`. You have to provide the hidden data, like `$rs` and also `$id`.

You should definitely read these about [mysql join](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqljoins.php) and [mysql left join](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlleftjoin.php). But I will try to give you an example based on your code, with fixed syntax. (Keep in mind, that I'm no mysql join expert, I did not test this code and also I do not know the joining conditions.) And also, the system structure is unclear.

As I understood, this what your tables do, correct?

- **mobsters** - *Users* table
- **items_firearms** - Links from *users* table to *items* table
- **db_firearms** - *Items* table

So basically, my example does this: It will have preloaded `$rs` value, from the *users* table. It will check, if there is a entry inside the *links* table and hook the result with them *items* table. However, if the *links* table or even the *items* table can return multiple entries, then this doesn't work and you need to loop your results in much more smarter way.

```
// I can only assume, that $id is the ID of the player
$id = 2;

// Since I dont know the $rs value, then Im going to make some up
$rs = array(
    'id' => 33,
    'firearm' => 'famas'
);

if ($rs['firearm']) {
    $result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT ifa.*, dbfa.* FROM `items_firearms` AS `ifa` LEFT JOIN `db_firearms` AS `dbfa` ON `ifa.shortname` = `dbfa.shortname` WHERE `ifa.player` = '$id'"));
    if ($result['id']) {
        mysql_query("UPDATE `mobsters` SET `firearm` = '' WHERE `id` = '$id'", $db);
    }
}
```

It is pretty clear, that you are new to PHP and mysql.. So I think you should probably edit your question and talk about your higher goal. Briefly mention, what your application are you building..? What are you trying to do with the mysql queries..? Maybe provide the table structure of your mysql tables..? I'm sure, that you will get your questions votes back to normal and also we can help you much better.

**NOTES**

- You have to quote these types of variables: `$rs[firearm]` -> `$rs['firearm']`
- If you want to check if your $rs['firearm'] equals something, then there is a better way then `$rs[firearm] != ""`. The most simple is `if ($rs['firearm']) {echo 'foo';}`, but will produce a notice message, when all errors reporting mode. You can use [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) and [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php), but keep in mind, that [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) checks whether the variable has been set.. Meaning, even if its false, then it has been set. [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) reacts to undefined and empty variable the same, without any messages.
- Also, `""` means `NULL`, so if you even need to use `""`, then use `NULL` instead...much neater way..
- I strongly recommend to use mysql class. You can understand the basics behind that idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7264203/load-db-password-and-keys-into-phps-memory-on-startup/7264426#7264426). This is gonna make things much more easier for you. Also, mysql class is a must-have when dealing with dynamic applications.
- `if ($rs3[$rs2[shortname]] < 1) { ..` makes no sense.. Do you want to check if the value is empty? Then (simple): `if (!$rs3[$rs2[shortname]]) { ..` and a very strict standard: `if (empty($rs3[$rs2[shortname]])) { ..`
- Also you have to quote your sql queries, see my examples above.
- Is the last mysql query missing $db?